# How to detect swiping or selecting event in XLPagerTabStrip swift

Tags: swift, tabbar, xlpagertabstrip

I am going to detect the swiping or selecting tab event in XLPagerTabStrip library in Swift 4.
I only need to get the tab index whenever selected tab is changed.
So I have checked library in Github but not found any good solutions.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So I didn't find a solution from the library itself but, I used **viewWillDisappear** and for every time you swipe away of the view this function will be called.
Should be written as follows in your **child view controller**:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //Do your thing here
}
```

You can read more about this callback function [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override updateContent

```
override func updateContent() {
    super.updateContent()
    // your code ....
}
```